# On the Numbers of Representations of a Number as a Sum of $2r$ Squares, Where $2r$ Does not Exceed Eighteen

Tags: group-theory, string-theory

I am reading the article "**Mathematicians Chase Moonshine’s Shadow**" **[1]**, and want to follow up on one of its sources "**On the Numbers of Representations of a Number as a Sum of $2r$ Squares, Where $2r$ Does not Exceed Eighteen**" by J. W. L. Glaisher **[2]**. Since I can't get my hand on the original, what would be the best book that summarizes the results of **[2]**?

[1] https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-chase-moonshine-string-theory-connections-20150312/

[2] https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/plms/s2-5.1.479

Comment: I could not find the article sources through that link. Meanwhile, I don't see why Glaisher (1907) should have been listed. You might like the book by Ono, The Web of Modularity. It is the sort of material that would have been in Glaisher

Comment: https://bookstore.ams.org/cbms-102/

Comment: It's avaliable on sci-hub

Comment: @WillJagy You are right! The article is not directly linked to in the story. The way I got to it was by first looking at "Mock Theta Functions" by Sander Pieter Zwegers. Then Googling on the subject "Mock Theta Functions", and coming across the paper "Theta Functions: The Problem of the Representation of Numbers as Sums of Squares" by Julio C. Andrade. That paper in turn had references to the 1907 paper by Glaisher! :) Crazy twist of events, I know.

Comment: start with this instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem  which gives some modern references. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks!

Comment: @user477805 Thanks!

Comment: Some hours later: I had intended to mention basic materials closer to my field; the articla does not mention the Leech Lattice, which is central to this. I like Thomas M. Thompson, From Error-Correcting Codes Through Sphere Packing to Simple Groups. The related technique by Conway that I used in an article is done best in Wolfgang Ebeling, Lattices and Codes. The  book by Conway and Sloane is encyclopedic and not for the curious.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books/about/From_Error_Correcting_Codes_Through_Sphe.html?id=ggqxuG31B3cC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false     and https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783658003593

Answer (score 1):

After digging through many books, the best I found on the subject are:

1. Grosswald, E. (1985). *Representations of integers as sums of squares.* New York: Springer.
2. Moreno, C. J., & Wagstaff, S. S. (2006). *Sums of squares of integers.* Boca Raton: Chapman & Hall/CRC.

Both books have references to Glaisher and his work. Both books expand on the subject in detail, using results in the field by other mathematicians (besides Glaisher).